# How to insert a new column in a huge MYSQL Database Table?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have this table in MYSQL databse which has about 10 million records/rows. I want to insert a new `column` in the table. However a simple insert column query doesn't seem to work well for me.

This is what I have tried,
`ALTER TABLE contacts ADD processed INT(11);`

I waited for about 5 hours, but nothing happened. Is there any way to insert a new column in such a huge table?

Hope I am clear with my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it production? What CPU do have? Is Server overloaded?

Comment: @RomanNewaza Its not in production its in local oly. I have 4GB ram i5 processor. and I dont think server is overloaded.

Comment: Is it Linux? Can you post the result of `uptime; free -m`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with windows.

Answer (score 11):

**If it's production:**

You should use [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html) of `Percona Toolkit`.

> pt-online-schema-change emulates the way that MySQL alters tables internally, but it works on a copy of the table you wish to alter. This means that the original table is not locked, and clients may continue to read and change data in it.
>
> pt-online-schema-change works by creating an empty copy of the table to alter, modifying it as desired, and then copying rows from the original table into the new table. When the copy is complete, it moves away the original table and replaces it with the new one. By default, it also drops the original table.

Or [oak-online-alter-table](http://openarkkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/openarkkit/doc/html/oak-online-alter-table.html) which is part of `openark kit`

> oak-online-alter-table allows for non blocking ALTER TABLE operations, table rebuilds and creating a table's ghost.

Altering tables will be slower, but it doesn't lock tables.

**If it's not production** and downtime is okay, try this approach:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts_tmp LIKE contacts;
ALTER TABLE contacts_tmp ADD COLUMN ADD processed INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
INSERT INTO contacts_tmp (contact_table_fields) SELECT * FROM contacts;
RENAME TABLE contacts_tmp TO contacts, contacts TO contacts_old;
DROP TABLE contacts_old;
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you ensure any of these tools will do the required process in less time? If yes, approximately how much ll it take? what would you suggest?

Comment: plus all I need is I want to do insert column in minimal time. Wondering whether there is a way?

Comment: It will take more CPU time

Comment: Also I have tried this method too. But it took too much time. That is the reason I posted the question.

Comment: INSERT INTO contacts_tmp (contact_table_fields) SELECT * FROM contacts; it can lose some data without lock . there is no better method to resolve that big table add new column.

Comment: MySQL's schema alteration abilities are severely limited compared to Postgres and other databases. Many operations like this require a lock and rebuild.